# How can I add a background color to the title label of a IKImageBrowserCell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I add a background color to the title label of a [IKImageBrowserCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Quartz/Reference/IKImageBrowserCell_Class/IKImageBrowserCell.html) ?

The text is not anymore visible because of the background, I would like to change the background of the label only.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Looks like, it is inherited from `NSObject`. may not possible to set background color. Because `UIBackgroundcolor` is property of `UIView`. It is having a view called `IKImageBrowserView` should be useful.